# Image not working in production, works good on localhost

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mantine, cloudflare-pages

I'm building a website with Next.js and Mantine. I want to put the Image with my logo in my Header so I used Image from next/image but the problem is that it's not working when i deploy it. It works perfectly on localhost.
Deployed:
[image]

Locally:
[image]

Code of my image that is clickable
`

```
<Link href={"/"} >
        <Image src="https://cdn.p33t.net/ZKAVDSZEFH.png" alt='logo' width={42} height={40} />
        </Link>
```

`
I tried using the local image but it was same. My image host is already added in the next config.
I expected it to be working same as on local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using Image component by Mantine instead of Next